# Extensive block on iphone

Tags: iphone

A friend of mine is dealing with a stalker that constantly creates new email addresses to message him. He has blocked all of them, but she keeps creating new ones. Is there a way to block her IP address specifically, so that any incoming messages from that address are blocked?

Comment: Aside from tha actual possibility of being able to block by IP Address, a phone doesn't have a fixed address, a laptop will use the address of whatever it's connected to, a domestic IP address is dynamic & may change at any time… & many people these days are behind CGNAT, which can mean an entire town shares the same public IP.

Comment: Many users also use webmail e.g. gmail, outlook and iCloud and the sender there will be the main server which is shared between many users